# How to access ExternalName service in kubernetes using minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, service, localhost, minikube

I understand that a service of type ExternalName will point to a specified deployment that is not exposed externally using the specified external name as the DNS name. I am using minikube in my local machine with docker drive. I created a deployment using a custom image. When I created a service with default type (Cluster IP) and Load Balancer for the specific deployment I was able to access it after port forwarding to the local ip address. This was possible for service type ExternalName also but accessible using the ip address and not the specified **external name**.

According to my understanding service of type ExternalName should be accessed when using the specified **external name**. But I wasn't able to do it. Can anyone say how to access an external name service and whether my understanding is correct?

This is the `externalName.yaml` file I used.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-hello-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: k8s-yaml-hello
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: k8s-hello-test.com
```

After port forwarding using `kubectl port-forward service/k8s-hello-test 3000:3000` particular deployment was accessible using `http://127.0.0.1:300`
But even after adding it to **etc/hosts** file, cannot be accessed using `http://k8s-hello-test.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to my understanding service of type ExternalName should be
> accessed when using the specified external name. But I wasn't able to
> do it. Can anyone say how to access it using its external name?

You are wrong, external service is for making external connections. Suppose if you are using the third party Geolocation API like https://findmeip.com you can leverage the **External Name** service.

> An ExternalName Service is a special case of Service that does not
> have selectors and uses DNS names instead. For more information, see
> the ExternalName section later in this document.

For example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: geolocation-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: api.findmeip.com
```

So your application can connect to **geolocation-service**, which which forwards requests to the external DNS mentioned in the service.

As **ExternalName** service does not have selectors you can not use the port-forwarding as it connects to POD and forwards the request.

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Comment: Thank you. I edited the external name service without selectors or ports and specified **externalName: google.com**. But this also doesn't get me to **google.com** when I use http://<servicename> . Could you provide with a suitable answer as accessing the externalName service is my main intension?

Comment: from where you are trying the curl ? is your cluster is private ? getting what error ? did you tried ping test or traceroute ? ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482750/curl-from-kubernetes-pod-to-externalname-service-hangs

Comment: I am using minikube in my local machine and trying the curl in the terminal. Error is `could not resolve host`. I tried out most of the curl commands given in the ref but all return the same error.

Comment: are you trying inside of container ? service could only be resolved inside the namespace. you can go inside any of running POD kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash and curl from inside of that.

Comment: No, I am currently trying it inside the node. Isn't it possible to access the external name service outside the container similar to the load balancer and ingress?

Comment: Only possible to access inside cluster it store data in K8s dns external name mean it uses to manage outgoing endpoint not expose any dns like ingress load balancer. In the first line of answer only said you are wrong

Comment: yes sure. But when I tried to curl from inside a running POD, it returns a 404 error. I am unable to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: did you tried ping and tracert to debug more ?

Comment: I am able to get response when using `postman-echo.com` as the `externalName` doing a curl within a running pod. I think it would be the security protocols of google.com or any other https that restricts the connection.

Comment: got that yes possible some security issue or so